# Swipe right from last screen to go to first screen in react navigation Material Top Tabs Navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-top-tabs

I am trying to achieve a flow in react navigation Material Top Tabs Navigator.

I want to swipe right on last screen in Material Top Tabs Navigator to go to first screen in the navigator. Vice versa if I swipe left on first screen in the navigator then it should take me to the last screen in the navigator.

There is no direct implementation in react navigation to achieve this behavior, neither could I found any solution on google.

Thank you